# Synthesis of compound metal oxides

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

When certain oxides are combined in a pre-determined stoichiometry and synthesized with a ceramic-like synthesis process(power-in-tube), multiple phases may be obtained which not necessarily is same as the original stoichiometry desired. For example, in the superconducting compound $\ce{YBa2Cu3O_{7−x}}$, other ratios such as $\ce{YBa2Cu4O_y}$ (Y124) or $\ce{Y2Ba4Cu7O_y}$ (Y247) might exist in the same material.

So the question is:

- What are some of the techniques of combining oxides to obtain desired major phase?

Online/book references or paper citations are also welcome apart from your valuable answers.